# Why is this PNG image rendered differently on Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: php, image, browser, png, gd

Here is the image url:
[Image](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-KKlZcpdQ6-c/UylD2xAAjbI/AAAAAAAACJo/iqmji0Pv6P8/s400/BeMshNt.png)

It gets yellow background on Firefox and green on Chrome and other browers.

Some screenshots:

On chrome:

[image: chrome]

On firefox:

[image: firefox]

When I try to save and look at it saved on desktop, it is green background.

***Sorry, my english isn't good***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an APNG file.  The main image (fallback) is green and the animation frame is yellow.  Chrome doesn't handle the APNG chunks so it falls back on the main image.  Here is a chunk listing; the acTL identifies it as an APNG.

```
# pngcheck -v *.png
File: BeMshNt.png (795 bytes)
  chunk IHDR at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    400 x 200 image, 8-bit palette, non-interlaced
  chunk acTL at offset 0x00025, length 8
    unknown private, ancillary, unsafe-to-copy chunk
  chunk PLTE at offset 0x00039, length 9: 3 palette entries
  chunk tRNS at offset 0x0004e, length 1: 1 transparency entry
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x0005b, length 295
    zlib: deflated, 32K window, maximum compression
  chunk fcTL at offset 0x0018e, length 26
    unknown private, ancillary, unsafe-to-copy chunk
  chunk fdAT at offset 0x001b4, length 300
    unknown private, ancillary, unsafe-to-copy chunk
  chunk tEXt at offset 0x002ec, length 27, keyword: Software
  chunk IEND at offset 0x00313, length 0
No errors detected in BeMshNt.png (9 chunks, 99.0% compression).
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you created a png file with 3 colors indexed in it : black, green and yellow. I think that Firefox uses the last color indexed to render the file, while chrome uses the second one. Dont ask me why ... I don't know. Hope It helped anyway.